# Handling HAL implementation: storage.cdrom.write_speeds

Tags: dbus, dvd-burning, cd-burning, hal

```
device.get('storage.cdrom.write_speeds')
```

This returns HAL list of ints, like:

```
[4284, 2342, 1202, 800]
```

How should these be handled, to recieve writing speed? Or better, how does one retrieve speeds for all media type burner can write: DVDs, CDs...

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM#Transfer_rates), calculation should be: value/150 for normal CDs, value/172.3 for audio CDs, value/1.32MB for DVDs. Which one to apply?

Also [HAL specification](http://people.freedesktop.org/~david/hal-spec/hal-spec.html#device-properties-storage-cdrom) seems to be saying that returned list of ints has metric value of kb/s, even though it seems to be in kB/s

Comment: I thought HAL was being phased out in favor of DeviceKit.

Comment: No, HAL is here to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! HAL really pises me off. Looks like it caches settings for last inserted medium. So, before I had anything in my burner, output looked like this:

```
$ lshal | grep write_speeds
storage.cdrom.write_speeds = {'4234', '2822', '1764', '706'} (string list)
```

After I inserted blank DVD:

```
$ lshal | grep write_speeds
storage.cdrom.write_speeds = {'11080', '5540'} (string list)
```

Maybe it helps to someone, HAL #fail